# How do you remotely execute a table valued function in Sql-Server 2000/5?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, distributed-transactions, user-defined-functions

I have a stored procedure (sql2005) that needs to call a table valued function on a remote server (sql2000).

My query is as follows:

```
select
    *
from
    mytable mt
     cross apply 
      opendatasource('sqloledb','Data Source=remoteserver;UID=user;Password=pass').mydatabase.dbo.mytvf
      (cast(param1 as numeric(20,0)), @param2, mt.param3)
```

I'm getting an incorrect syntax error near 'cast'. Is it possible to execute a tvf with this notation? Should I somehow be using openrowset? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not positive which is why I didn't list as answer but I think you need to specify WITH NOLOCK in order to protect the remote server from blocking.  You become susceptible to dirty reads but that might be the issue.

Comment: on the table i'm starting from? select * from mytable mt with (nolock)?

Comment: Is it ok to be doing an opendatasource to a TVF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the official word.  You cannot call a UDF in this way.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/276758/remote-table-valued-function-calls-are-not-allowed

Looks like Mircosoft is working on the ability in a future version though.